# How to discard all characters after regex group

Tags: regex, textinput

I want to only allow a positive double with 2 digits.

I got this, which is working, but after I successfully match the pattern it starts over again instead of discarding incoming characters.

```
([1-9]+[\d]*(\.|,)?[\d]{0,2})
```

```
Input

12.34  //Pass Filter  
12.340 //Rejected - Zero cannot be the first character
12.345 //Pass Filter - It pass, but it is supposed to be rejected since it has 3 decimal digits
```

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using? If this is part of a program, show us the relevant program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want partial matches, you can anchor the string, and put the zero and comma in a character class.

If you want to match the `.` or `,` zero or 1 times you can use `?` instead of `*`

```
^[1-9]+\d*[.,]*\d{0,2}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/br7dGz/1).

Comment: EDIT: This actually did not work as intended.
I can still add more than two decimals, but if the third is a 0 it removes all the decimals. This might be a Flutter thing.

Comment: @JoelBroström Can you update the regex101 link with strings that should and should not match? https://regex101.com/r/cxNd97/1

Comment: Thanks for your commitment!
With my original regex all the strings that should work does work, but it also allows for substrings within the faulty strings to register as valid strings. Here is a updated list with more detailed requirements.   https://regex101.com/r/ObuuIi/1

Comment: @JoelBroström You might use this `^[1-9]+\d*[.,]*\d{0,2}$` https://regex101.com/r/br7dGz/1 But what do you mean in this part `12.345 //OK  - I want 5 to be discarded` by the 5 to be discarded? Do you want to match `12.34` ? And if so, why should `11.111` not match in that case?

Comment: The writing was confusing. 
What I ment was that with the regex I had 12.345 passed, but I did not want it to pass. 12.345 has 3 decimal digits, but I said I only wanted two in my regex. Yet it passed.

Comment: Your solution works well, except for the fact that flutter erase the whole string when I type a character that does not conform to the pattern.
12.34 will work but when I add 5 the whole string will be discarded. Ideally I would not be able to add the 5 since it does not match the pattern.
I realize this is an implementation issue and not something faulty with your regex expression. If you are familiar with flutter I am using `FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^[1-9]+\d*[.,]*\d{0,2}$'));` with a normal TextField.

Comment: Could you change your answer to `^[1-9]+\d*[.,]*\d{0,2}$` since it does exactly what I asked for? If you do I'll mark your answer as the right one.

Comment: @JoelBroström Sure, I have updated the answer.